# Force title on GNU screen

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen, window-title

By default, the title of a screen session is the name of the last command entered, which is fine for me, but in some cases I'd like to change it. I know the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, but it only changes the title until the next command, and I'd like it to stay there until I decide otherwise.

**EDIT:**
Here's the `preexec` function I found in my `.zshrc`

```
if [[ "$TERM" == "screen" ]]; then
   local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|-*)]}
   echo -n "\ek$CMD\e\\"
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depends how things are set up, but by default, something like this should work.

```
settitle() {
    printf "\033k$1\033\\"
}
```

Then run:

`settitle NEWTITLE`.

See [screen title docs](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_9.html#SEC37) and [GNU screen faq](http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#how_can_screen_use_xterm_s_title_bar) for more details.

Given <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> is only changing it until the next command, it's probably being set by `$PS1` (all shells), or `$PROMPT_COMMAND`/`DEBUG trap` (bash only) or `precmd`/`preexec` (zsh only).

You should look for any place that `\e` or `\033` appears with `k` or `\\` after it, basically like my `settitle` example above.

**UPDATE**

You said you had a custom `preexec`.

Why not change it to this:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == "screen" ]]; then
   local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|-*)]}
   echo -n "\ek${TITLE:-$CMD}\e\\"
fi
```

Then you can set a custom title by running:

```
TITLE="my title"
```

and unset the title by running

```
TITLE=
```

Don't forget to change `precmd` and `$PS1` as well if necessary.

**ASIDE**

You could even extend this to all terminals (e.g. `xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, etc.) by not hard coding the `\ek` and `\e\\`.

This is how I do it:

```
terminit()
{
    # determine the window title escape sequences
    case "$TERM" in
    aixterm|dtterm|putty|rxvt|xterm*)
        titlestart='\033]0;'
        titlefinish='\007'
        ;;
    cygwin)
        titlestart='\033];'
        titlefinish='\007'
        ;;
    konsole)
        titlestart='\033]30;'
        titlefinish='\007'
        ;;
    screen*)
        # status line
        #titlestart='\033_'
        #titlefinish='\033\'
        # window title
        titlestart='\033k'
        titlefinish='\033\'
        ;;
    *)
        if type tput >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
            if tput longname >/dev/null 2>&1
            then
                titlestart="$(tput tsl)"
                titlefinish="$(tput fsl)"
            fi
        else
            titlestart=''
            titlefinish=''
        fi
        ;;
    esac
}


# or put it inside a case $- in *i* guard
if test -t 0; then
    terminit
fi

# set the xterm/screen/etc. title
settitle()
{
    test -z "${titlestart}" && return 0

    printf "${titlestart}$*${titlefinish}"
}
```

Then you can change your `preexec` to:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == "screen" ]]; then
   local CMD=${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|-*)]}
   settitle "${TITLE:-$CMD}"
fi
```

Comment: The command you give does exactly the same thing as `Ctrl-A A`. And about the prompt, you mean I have to modify `$PS1` whenever I want the title not to change?

Comment: I mean check it doesn't contain ESC k something ESC \.  Ditto PROMPT_COMMAND.

Comment: ESC could be written `\e` or `\033`.

Comment: The screen title docs links should have the necessary information

Comment: `printf "${titlestart}$*${titlefinish}"` should be `printf "${titlestart}%s${titlefinish}" "$*"`. Otherwise `printf` will interpret any format codes that might happen to be embedded in the argument(s) to `settitle`.

Answer (score 6):

If your window title reflects the application currently running in the window, it's because your shell is doing that. If it's doing that, it's because your distribution, your system administrator or you configured it to.

If the command appears as the window title while the command is running, this is done by the `preexec` function (in zsh), or an [emulation thereof under bash](https://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command).

If the title changes when each command completes, this is done by the `precmd` function in zsh, the `PROMPT_COMMAND` parameter in bash, or as part of the prompt (`PS1` parameter) in any shell. (The command to change the title is an escape sequence emitted by any application as part of the terminal's output stream, so it can be embedded in a prompt.)

Look for an escape sequence like `\e]0;new title\a`, `\e]2;new title\a` or `\eknew title\e\\` in your shell initialization file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, …). If there's nothing relevant, the setting may be in a system file (e.g. `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/zsh/zshrc`); then overwrite that parameter or function in your own initialization file.

See [Mikel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/force-title-on-gnu-screen/7382#7382) for an overridable title setting in `preexec`.

Comment: Thanks, you made it very clear. I have indeed found a `preexec` function defined in my .zshrc.

The thing is, that's the behavior I want... most of the time. I'd like to be able to disable it on the fly on one specific screen. There's maybe a variable that I can get in the `preexec` function when I manually set the title, or something like that?

Comment: @gregseth: It's a bit hard to explain in general, but if you post your `preexec` function, I or someone else can probably suggest a simple change.

Comment: I was going to mention `preexec`, but Greg didn't say he was using `zsh`.  That'll teach me. ;-)

Comment: @Mikel: My explanation was better than yours, but your new `preexec` design is better than mine.

Comment: I agree. :-)  My original answer was trying to teach the OP to find the answer for himself.  Yours was more immediately helpful.  Either way, we all win.