# Permanently fixed screen titles

Tags: gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force title on GNU screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/force-title-on-gnu-screen)

I know how to set a title in screen (<kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>). However, every time I do so, if I change directories or run a command, the window title changes. I wish it to not do this. How do I tell screen "use this title until I explicitly tell you otherwise"?

My company provides a fairly sophisticated default `.zshrc` as part of default configuration, so there may be -- and probably is -- some kind of magic prompt alteration that's causing this change. Where do I begin looking for what to undo to get rid of it?